# Filebeat can't connect to logstash on another server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, filebeat

Filebeat (`11.11.11.11`) can't connect to logstash (`22.22.22.22`) on another server (`connection reset by peer`). But filebeat services from other servers can do it.

Also I **can** connect from this server(`11.11.11.11`) using **telnet** to this port (`telnet 22.22.22.22 5044`).

I can see `"failed":34816,"total":34816` in filebeat logs:

```
root@stage /var/log/filebeat # tail filebeat
2018-05-09T08:30:48.298Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:124  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":2390,"time":2392},"total":{"ticks":539690,"time":539696,"value":539690},"user":{"ticks":537300,"time":537304}},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"e0b9a5bb-4446-4ee1-a6f4-e2b0ccfb1677","uptime":{"ms":2340029}},"memstats":{"gc_next":205064832,"memory_alloc":146205312,"memory_total":29895393656}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":39,"running":48}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"events":{"batches":17,"failed":34816,"total":34816},"write":{"bytes":17029928,"errors":17}},"pipeline":{"clients":3,"events":{"active":4119,"retry":69632}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":139}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.24,"15":0.43,"5":0.31,"norm":{"1":0.03,"15":0.0538,"5":0.0388}}}}}}
2018-05-09T08:30:48.391Z    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:92   Failed to publish events: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34626->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:49.943Z    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34632->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:50.943Z    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:92   Failed to publish events: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34632->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:51.383Z    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34634->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:52.383Z    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:92   Failed to publish events: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34634->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:53.942Z    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34636->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:54.942Z    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:92   Failed to publish events: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34636->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:55.407Z    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34654->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2018-05-09T08:30:56.407Z    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:92   Failed to publish events: write tcp 11.11.11.11:34654->22.22.22.22:5044: write: connection reset by peer
```

filebeat is already the newest version (6.2.4).
logstash is already the newest version (1:6.2.4-1).

How can it be solved or investigated?

**Update**:
If I switch off the logstash, the error changes:

```
ERROR   pipeline/output.go:74   Failed to connect:
dial tcp 22.22.22.22:5044: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure about this but for sure you can enable debug for having more information:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/enable-filebeat-debugging.html

i would also check the logstash and filebeat configurations:

Logstash:

in this case is receiving and should have an input configuration like the one below

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
    ssl  => false
  }
}
```

be sure logstash service has the permission to open a listen socket on the machine. check it with a

```
netstat -l
```

Filebeat:

check if filebeat is pointing to the correct logstash port

```
 output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["22.22.22.22:5044"]
```

Comment: Thank you, `ssl => false` became necessary in the last update.